# Export from Saved system log

Tags: powershell, windows-event-log, eventviewer

Using powershell, is there any way we can export system event logs from a saved system event log file (*.evt). Get-Eventlog does not recognize the "-logname "Saved system log"".

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Path** parameter.

```
Get-WinEvent -Path filename.evt
```

Comment: Get-WinEvent -Path E:\path\filename.evt  does work, though only on Windows Vista/2008 R2 and higher OS.
I have been trying to get this to work on a windows server 2003, but could not find anything on this yet. Am not really sure of remoting to a Win 2003 machine